# How to fetch Record in a faster manner from SQLDataReader In C#

Tags: c#

we have a stored procedure  , which results data as below.

```
testCol1    testCol2  testCol3  testCol4  testCol5
 124       1234       4543      4532       5564
 123       1235       4546      4537       5565
```

it has 190,000 records.

I am trying to fetch data in `List<TestData>` type and then pass it to third party.
 below is the code:

```
public class TestData
{
    public int testCol1 { get; set; }
    public int testCol2 { get; set; } 
    public string testCol3 { get; set; }
    public double? testCol4 { get; set; }
    public int testCol5 { get; set; }
}
```

```
var inputs = new List<TestData>();
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(fitchConnectionString))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
{
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "dbo.ReadAll_ForTest";
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
    con.Open();
    using (SqlDataReader dr = new SqlDataReader(cmd.ExecuteReader()))
    {
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            inputs.Add(new TestData()
            {
                testCol1 = (int)dr["testCol1"];
                testCol2 = (int)dr["testCol2"];
                testCol3 =(string)dr["testCol3"];
                testCol4 = (double)dr["testCol4"];
                testCol5 = (int)dr["testCol5"];

            });
        }
    }
}

//pass to third party
var output = thirdparty.Convert(inputs).ToArray();
```

its working fine , however is taking lots of time to fetch the data.
is there is a way we can fetch data in faster manner?

Comment: @Caramiriel , sorry i have corrected it.

Comment: What format does the client expect the data to be in? Why does it have to be all of 190k records?

Comment: On a side note be sure to set the `CommandType` of the command to StoredProcedure. Your added line: `cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;`

Comment: Use EntityFramework

Comment: You can optimize reading slightly by using `.GetOrdinal` to not look up columns by name all the time, but the real issue is likely that you're stuffing 190K items in a list which has to be dynamically grown and allocated before being processed into a new array of 190K items (at which point it's presumably passed off again somewhere). Allocation isn't free. How have you established that reading from SQL Server is the actual bottleneck? How fast is an empty `Read()` loop, which just measures the execution time and network overhead?

Comment: @shahkalpesh . client accepts data in array of `TestData` type .record count is in the range of 150k - 190k.

Comment: If change the volume of records retrieved is not an option then you should look if there are any optimizations to be made in the query that the stored procedure is executing. Profile the execution plan of the stored procedure.

Comment: @Harshit pre-allocating enough space in `List<TestData>` should help (if you can have an arbitrary big enough number beforehand without running `SELECT COUNT(*)`). Alternatively loading everything with `DataTable` and then constructing your list (then you know the number of rows) even if it uses much more memory. You'd probably need to run this through the profiler to determine what's slow here, it's too easy to try to optimize a minor detail without any effective/visible impact on performance.

Comment: Build. Measure. Improve. You have built and now you want to improve. Don't skip the measure stage, find out what exactly is slowing you down.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to specify types explicitly, so that the framework doesn't have to figure out what you mean. Get the ordinals (indices) in advance, and extract the exact type from the column:

```
using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    var testCol1Idx = dr.GetOrdinal("testCol1");
    var testCol2Idx = dr.GetOrdinal("testCol2");
    var testCol3Idx = dr.GetOrdinal("testCol3");
    var testCol4Idx = dr.GetOrdinal("testCol4");
    var testCol5Idx = dr.GetOrdinal("testCol5");

    while (dr.Read())
    {
        inputs.Add(new TestData()
        {
            testCol1 = dr.GetInt32(testCol1Idx);
            testCol2 = dr.GetInt32(testCol2Idx);
            testCol3 = dr.GetString(testCol3Idx);
            testCol4 = dr.GetDouble(testCol4Idx);
            testCol5 = dr.GetInt32(testCol5Idx);
        });
    }
}
```

Other than that, 100K+ are a lot of records. Do you really need all of them? Try to work with a subset of the data, or aggregate data before using them.